# Why is this third div being pushed down?

Tags: html, css

My question is why is that third div( class= "right") goes downward??

I tried using vertical-align:top; also but didn't work.

**I want div.nav to be at mid and div.right to be at right with *all three of them being at the same top postition***

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

.left{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav{
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin:auto;
}

.right{
    float:right;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.group:before,
.group:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.group:after{
    clear:both;
}

.group{
    zoom:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaming world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top-header group">
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="nav">Nav</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren’t all three divs display:inline-block?

Comment: You gave it `display: block;`. display: block will take a 100% width

Comment: nav is in the regular flow, then right floats but will go under nav. make nav also float or use from the parent a flex or grid display.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 , nav is here set to 20% of width ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus still not working when removing it hahaha

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 of course, read my other comment ;) , .right moves below .nav before floatting, that's how float elements behave **since ever**. the non floatting element is to be placed behind , not before. example https://jsfiddle.net/sz9rakw5/ - https://jsfiddle.net/sz9rakw5/1/ with or without a width set and borders to show where nav stands

Comment: You can just float all three elements to the left, with their widths set to - 40% 20% 40% respectively. And `vertical-align` doesn't works with floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

##### Answering your question

You used `display: block;`. display: block will take a 100%. If you want the div to only take the width of the item itself then use `display: inline-block;`

---

##### Fixing your code

Use `display: flex;` with `justify-content: space-between;` and remove all the other stuff. You can also add other divs in the header but flex will position them perfectly

That means you can also remove the classes from the divs in the header

Optimized Code:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaming world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top-header group">
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="nav">Nav</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

---

#### Example with more Divs in the header:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaming world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top-header group">
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

floatting elements will make a **break before floatting if anything in the regular flow stands before it** , that's why `.right` shows right under `.nav`.

You can set `.nav` **after** the floatting elements in the code, so it doesn't disturb the floatting elements.

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

.left{
    float:left; 
}

.nav{
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin:auto;
}

.right{
    float:right; 
}

.group:before,
.group:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.group:after{
    clear:both;
}

.group{
    zoom:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaming world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top-header group">
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
            <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Nowdays, flex or grid is used for this

- flex

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

.top-header {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gaming world</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="top-header group">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

- grid

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 20% auto;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.left {}

.nav {}

.right {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gaming world</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="top-header group">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! good reply. It worked

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    /*background-image:url('../images/GOW_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;*/
}

.left{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav{
  display: inline-block;

  
}

.right{
  display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.group:before,
.group:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.group:after{
    clear:both;
}

.group{
    zoom:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaming world</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top-header group">
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="nav">Nav</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Try using `display:inline-block;` on all divs. Then you can set the location of the nav with `width` of the first div

Comment: Not a bad solution but I’m guessing you are going to have troubles when screen width varies. (Response). The flex box solution will space out well for a pretty large variety of display screen widths.